# Diferencia entre horas PHP

Tags: php, mysql

De nuevo preguntando.. saludos

Lo que pretendo es poner el usuario, la hora de entrada, la hora de salida y la difrencia entre la h.entrada y la de Salida... para ello:

Tengo una tabla para almacenar las entradas y salidas de trabajadores

(Usuario | Fecha |movimiento(Entrada ó Salida) | Hora | Lugar)

mediante una consulta Mysql busco todos los trabajadores,
con otra consulta dentro de la anterior, busco cuando ha fichado el trabajador.
Y en un Array, guardo la hora de entrada y la de salida
y lo intento presentar en una tabla HTML

al ejecutar el archivo PHP, como algunos trabajadores han fichado solo la entrada, otros no han hecho ni la entrada ni la salida, me produce gran cantidad de errores al restar la hora de entrada y la de salida....pero lo mas grave es que en trabajador que ha entrado y luego ha salido, la tabla, muestra perfectamente la hora de entrada y la de salida, pero no registra el resultado de la diferencia entre la hora de entrada y la de salida. Os pongo el código a ver si me mostrais la luz del camino....gracias...

```
<?php
include '/conectadB.php';
$anno=date('Y');
$dia=date('Y-m-d');
$encontradas="";
$usuario="";
$horaZ=0;
$horaXZ=array();
$hora0="";
$hora1="";
$diff="";
echo "<table border = 1  cellspacing = 0 cellpadding = 2>"; 

// Busca TRABAJADORES ******************************************************************
$sql="SELECT * FROM trabajadores WHERE Estado=1 AND Delegacion=1 order by Nombre ASC" ;
$strabajadores=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());  

while($rowu = mysql_fetch_array($strabajadores))

{
$usuario=$rowu['Nombre'];

// Busca los fichajes del trabajador ****************************************************

$sql="SELECT * FROM fichar WHERE Usuario=".$rowu['id']." AND date('Y-m-d')=".$dia;
//echo $sql;
$sfichar=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sfichar))

{

array_push ( $horaXZ,$row['hora'] );

$encontradas=$encontradas."<td>".$row['movimiento']."</td>"."<td>".$row['hora']."</td>";

}// Fichajes *****************************************************************************

$diff=date_diff($horaXZ[0],$horaXZ[1]) ; 

  echo "<tr><td >".utf8_encode($usuario)."</td>"."<td>".$encontradas."</td>"."<td>".$diff."</td>"."</tr>";

$encontradas="";
unset ($horaXZ);
}// trabajadores


echo "</tr></table><P>";

?>
```

Comment: No creo que sea necesario hacer dos consultas. Tampoco se entiende mucho qué es lo que quieres filtrar en la 2ª consulta ¿?... Por otra parte, quizá tu diseño también esté mal planteado y eso conduce a confusiones. Podrías tener simplemente dos columnas de tipo `DATETIME` llamadas por ejemplo `entrada` y `salida` donde almacenarías **fecha y hora** de entrada y **fecha y hora** de salida. Así, calcular la diferencia sería lo de menos. Tu problema principal, a mi juicio, es que lo tienes mal planteado.

Comment: Saludos. Me parece en una tabla y en mismas columnas estas registrando la entrada y salida (no es que una columna -para el mismo día- corresponda a entrada y otra salida); debes incluir en tu proceso (digamos) hasta que hora se considera entrada (tiempo de tolerancia, retardo, inasistencia...) y para la salida a partir de que hora puede registrar así determinar con 2 registros sería uno de entrada y salida, y con solo uno "saber" (más bien asumir) corresponde a la entrada o salida y proceso como definir que valor establecer o como dejar el estatus por el "dato faltante".